# How is the notion of $G$-function related to that of the replicator equation?

Tags: game-theory

**Background**:

While studying "[Evolutionary Game Theory, Natural Selection, and Darwinian Dynamics](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/evolutionary-game-theory-natural-selection-and-darwinian-dynamics/D18CD60B6E656B96E65F936C265C32CE)", I am pretty confused about the notion of G-function (fitness-generating function), that is extensively used throughout the whole book, and its relation to the well-known [replicator equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replicator_equation).

In particular, the book defines vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ as strategies and population density, respectively. Then, it defines fitness function $H_{i}(\cdot,\cdot,\cdot)$, associated with population type $i$, as follows.

$$\dot{x}_{i} := x_{i}H_{i}(\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{x})$$

Later, aiming for "collapsing a population's fitness functions into a single $G$-function", they define the notion of $G$-function as below (on the page 77).

> A function $G(v, \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{x})$ is a fitness generating
> function ($G$-function) for the population dynamics if and only if
>
> $$G(v, \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{x})|_{v = u_{i}} = H_{i}(\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{x}), \quad\text{for some }i.$$

The authors use $G$-functions to model both elements of the Darwinian Dynamics, i.e., population dynamics (*) and strategy dynamics (**), say,

$$\dot{x}_{i} = x_{i}G(v, \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{x})|_{v = u_{i}}\quad (*)$$

$$\dot{u}_{i} = \sum_{j}\Big(G(v, \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{x})|_{v = u_{ij}} - G(v, \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{x})|_{v = u_{i}}\Big)q_{ij}u_{ij}\quad (**)$$

where $u_{ij}$ the strategy associated with a phenotype ratio $x_{ij}$ and $q_{ij}:=\frac{x_{ij}}{x_{i}}$.

We already know that replicator equation represents the population dynamics in an evolutionary game. But in the whole book, there is not a single appearance of "replicator dynamics" or "replicator equation".

**Questions**:

Can one pinpoint how may the cited $G$-function be compared to the replicator equation? Is the replicator equation a special case of the $G$-function above? If so, how can one derive the former of the latter?